# Popup window just below the address bar , how to handle this using selenium webdrier

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, popupwindow

I am using selenium webdriver to automate my application , using  firefox and chrome as two browser. My application require Gemsafe software support, due to this a popup is appearing on when I am launching the application just below the the address bar, text is “Allow and don’t allow”. I am not able to handle this popup. Can anyone know help me out on this ?

Comment: Do you have the code of the popup?

Comment: No, I don't have. :(

Comment: I have a few things you can try, but I want to know if you've already ruled some of them out.

Comment: I have tried that switch to alert code, its not working. Please suggest i will try.

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of the box that you're trying to close?

Comment: I have attached the below screen shot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think this is the small yellow toolbar right below the address bar that is warning you that Gemsafe, etc. needs to be enabled on the site and prompts the customer to Allow or not.

If so, this is not part of the HTML of the page and cannot be interacted with using Selenium. The simple way to determine this is to right-click on the "popup" and see if you can Inspect Element, etc. If not, it's part of the browser and can't be accessed using Selenium.

I would recommend that you set each browser up in such a way (before the tests) that the Gemsafe software support is already set up. I think a customer would only have to click Allow once for a site, just do that on each supported browser (sounds like only Chrome and FF). There may be some browsers where additional setup is required to permanently allow this. You will have to do research for those browsers.

Comment: Yes, when we launch the url Gemsafe popup appear below the address bar which prompt for allow gemsafe to ask for pin of that customer. I have tried right-click on the "popup" - Inspect Element,its not showing any ID. For setting each browser with Gemsafe software support is already set up, how we can do that ? because each time we launch a browser it open new profile. If you know how to set can you help . Thanks..